# Call a C program from php and read program output

Tags: php, c, linux

Could some one explain me how to run a C program from a php script and store console output of the C program to a php variable?

My program prints an integer value on the console using C printf() function. I want to read this value and store it in a php variable.
I am using linux. I tried exec but it doesn't display the variable value once echoed to the page

This the code snippet I am using.

```
exec("Release/matchface image1.jpg image2.jpg", $output);
while( list(,$row) = each($output) ) {
  echo $row. "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll want to use the [**`shell_exec()`**](https://www.php.net/shell_exec) function *(quoting)* :

> Execute command via shell and return
> the complete output as a string

Which means something that will look like this :

```
$output = shell_exec('/path/to/your/program');
```

Or, you could use the [**`backtick operator`**][2] -- which would do exactly the same thing *(quoting)* :

> PHP will attempt to execute the
> contents of the backticks as a shell
> command; the output will be returned

And, in code :

```
$output = `/path/to/your/program`;
```

Comment: this doesn't print anything on browser.

Comment: Even if you use `echo $output;` ? Are you sure your C program is echoing on stdout ?

Comment: Yep it does. I ran it in terminal using exact parameter parsed to exec() and it prints an integer.

Comment: @Niroshan: That doesn't necessarily mean it's printing on `STDOUT`. It could be printing on `STDERR`. And make sure your path is correct. Don't forget that the environment is different.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I am using printf(), so there is nothing wrong with that I guess. Above answer works fine for a simple main() function with a printf(). I guess problem must be somewhere in my c code. Thank you everyone for offering help :)

Comment: I know it's not the case in this example, but just a word of caution: if you ever take arguments from a user in the shell_exec(), you should strongly consider using the escapeshellcmd() function (e.g. shell_exec('ls -latr ' . escapeshellcmd($arg);) otherwise, if the user-entered field arg is '; rm \*.\*' they'll remove all your files, or inject any code they wish...