# Run c/java/python with PHP?

Tags: java, php, python, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call a C program from php and read program output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555912/call-a-c-program-from-php-and-read-program-output)

How can I run a C/Java/Python/etc. program when using PHP?

Comment: [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) [is](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) [your](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) [friend](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for PHPs [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function:

```
exec('myapp');
```

Comment: sorry,i am fool,i still cant solve my proplem

Answer (score 0):

Use [`popen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) function. This will grant you access to `stdout` or `stdin`, but only one of them.

So, python application:

```
$handle = popen('python /home/user/Documents/somefile.py', 'r');
var_dump(fread($handle));
pclose($handle);
```

But if you need to use both `stdin` and `stdout` - you should take a look at [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).

Comment: sorry,i am really fool,i still can't solve my proplem  :(

Comment: and what are you trying to do?

Comment: faster,faster...people can visit my website more faster,can you give me some suggestions

Comment: tell me what are you trying to get and i shall give you some suggestions ;)

Comment: i want some methods to let my website faster,can you help me?

Comment: Use nginx (heard that's makes sense to handle statics - css, js, images...), force client-side caching, use server-side caching for your PHP output (when some code gives exactly the same results in some situations - cache these results!). There are a lot of optimization ways...

Comment: Hmm,this is what i really want,you mean cache....can help me?

Comment: i have had no other deal with caches than Magento ones =)